# Nested dictionary from data in a text file

Tags: python, json, file, dictionary, text

I am new with python and I am trying to create a dictionary that outputs in a JSON file, this with data from a text file. So the text file would be this one.

```
   557e155fc5f0 557e155fc5f0 1 557e155fc602 1
   557e155fc610 557e155fc610 2
   557e155fc620 557e155fc620 1 557e155fc626 1
   557e155fc630 557e155fc630 1 557e155fc636 1
   557e155fc640 557e155fc640 1
   557e155fc670 557e155fc670 1 557e155fc698 1
   557e155fc6a0 557e155fc6a0 1 557e155fc6d8 1
```

And the desired output for the first two lines would be

```
   { "functions": [
        {
         "address": "557e155fc5f0",
         "blocks": [
             "557e155fc5f0": "calls":{1}
             "557e155fc602": "calls":{1}
             ]
        },
        {
         "address": " 557e155fc610",
         "blocks": [
             " 557e155fc610": "calls":{2}
             ]
        },
```

I have wrote a script to begin but I don't know how to continue.

```
   import json

   filename = 'calls2.out'       # here the name of the output file

   funs = {}
   bbls = {}
   with open(filename) as fh:     # open file 
       for line in fh:            # walk line by line
           if line.strip():       # non-empty line?
                rtn,bbl = line.split(None,1) # None means 'all whitespace', the default
        for j in range(len(bbl)):
            funs[rtn] =  bbl.split()

   print(json.dumps(funs, indent=2, sort_keys=True))

   #json = json.dumps(fun, indent=2, sort_keys=True)  # to save it into a file
   #f = open("fout.json","w")
   #f.write(json)
   #f.close()
```

this script gives me this output

```
   "557e155fc5f0": [
       "557e155fc5f0",
       "1",
       "557e155fc602",
       "1"
     ],
     "557e155fc610": [
       "557e155fc610",
       "2"
     ],
     "557e155fc620": [
       "557e155fc620",
        "1",
      "557e155fc626",
       "1"
     ],
```

Comment: `"557e155fc5f0": "calls":{1}` is not valid syntax. What's the `:{1}` supposed to be?

Comment: I edited my answer for if you need the "calls" as key, after you marked it, just so you don't overlook it, in case you need it (;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
funs[rtn] =  bbl.split()
```

Here you add `"557e155fc5f0", "1"` as value to the `rtn`key, because bbl is `557e155fc5f0 1` at this point, but you want to add it as a dictionary.

```
temp_dict = {bbl.split()[0]: bbl.split()[1]}
funs[rtn] = temp_dict
```

This will give you following json:

```
{
  "557e155fc6a0": {
    "557e155fc6a0": "1"
  }
}
```

If you need the calls as key in the json you'd need to extend a bit:

```
temp_dict = {bbl.split()[0]: {"calls": bbl.split()[1]}}
funs[rtn] = temp_dict
```

Gives you this:

```
{
  "557e155fc6a0": {
    "557e155fc6a0": {
      "calls": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

Also, your example json is malformed, I assume you want sth like this:

```
{
"functions": {
    "address": "557e155fc5f0",
    "blocks": {
        "557e155fc5f0": {
            "calls": 1
        },
        "557e155fc602": {
            "calls": 1
        }
    }
},
    "address": " 557e155fc610",
    "blocks": {
        "557e155fc610": {
            "calls": 2
        }
    }
}
```

I'd try an Online JSON Editor for testing/creating examples.

Hope it helps!